# How to make browser source code visible for dojo widgets

Tags: javascript, dojo, widget

I created a dojo widget declaratively and once it got rendered in the browser I just could see the declared widget in the browser source and could not see the contents inside it. 
How can I see the contents inside the widget DOM? I know inspecting the DOM makes the inner source code visible. But I want to know if there is a way that I can see the full source code when I ask the browser to show me the source code.

Comment: What do you mean by 'full source code'?

Comment: Eg) When I right click on a browser say, Chrome and click on Page Source, I should be able to see the full source of what was rendered within the widget after Dojo's lifecycle.  Currently what I could see id just the declares widget like <div dojo-data-type="a/b/c"/>

Comment: There is no such feature in Chrome or any browser. "View source" only shows the HTML text that the server handed to your browser, before anything was processed. What you're looking for is the Javascript Debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Calling toString() on any function can show source code of that function. May be this can help you to show source code for DOJO widget.

functionaName.toString();

Answer (score 0):

Use `domNode` property to see the top level dom node for your widget.

In order to catch this property get the widget first by id using  `registry.byId` [dijit/registry](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/registry.html)

Example here, you can see the property in the console:

https://jsbin.com/wizodibaqo/edit?html,css,console,output

For reference:

> domNode - The top-level node in the widget. All widgets have a DOM
>   Node attached to them, either through the srcNodeRef passed during
>   instantiation, or a one created by the widget framework when declaring
>   one programmatically. This is a real DOM Node, and is common in all
>   Dijits. If you wish to show or hide a widget, for example, you would
>   modify the CSS property display for the .domNode:

https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/info.html